# Can I make a constexpr object of std::set?

Tags: c++, stl, constexpr, stdset, initialization-order

I need a const object of std::set, which will be used in many other cpp files.
Since that the initializing-order of each parts of the app is undefined, I may get a empty set when I initialize other const objects with this std::set obj.

So, I want make this std::set as constexpr, but it can not be compiled.
I want to have:

```
constexpr std::set<int> EARLIER_SET = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Is there a way to get it? or not at all?

Comment: Why do you need it to be a set? What are you doing with the set and the data it contains? Can it be done with other data structures (like perhaps a plain array)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `constexpr` here since `std::set` has no `constexpr` constructors.

What you can do though is declare the variable as an `inline const` variable and that will allow you to include it in every translation unit and provide an initializer.  That would look like

```
//header file
inline const std::set<int> EARLIER_SET = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Answer (score 4):

Not at all in the standard library.

But you might be interested in: https://github.com/serge-sans-paille/frozen

```
constexpr frozen::set<int, 3> EARLIER_SET = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

would then be valid.